# how to include small image with google share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-api, social-networking

```
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.website.com/coolwebsite/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/g_co.jpg" alt="Share on Google Plus"></a></li>
```

How could I add **a message** and a **small image** to share with the above *(URL that currently does)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.

**Option 1: Microdata**

This would be the best way in my opinion, but it may take a bit of getting used to. Microdata is very powerful and there are many implementations for different types of data.  The standard can be found on [schema.org](http://schema.org).

Google has a nice tool for testing Microdata, it's called the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).

**Option 2: Open Graph Protocol**

This is a bit easier to implement as it's simply just adding `meta` tags that are named following the protocol listed on [their website](http://ogp.me/).

Example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title about post" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/coolwebsite/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com/images/g_co.jpg" />
```

Comment: Well, I'm using Open Graph Protocol for Facebook share -- could they use the same images from the og: image ? I'v read there are different size requirements.

Comment: Yes, they can use the same images from `og:image`. Just make sure the images are large enough to display in both. For instance, Google I believe requires the image to have a height of at least `120px`. I'd have to check on Facebook's requirement. -- update: min requirement for Facebook looks like `100x100`